# How to get file (image for example) from backend and display it in frontend

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

How can I get an object of type Prestataires that contains some inputs of type text and file (image) only the URL that is stored in a folder from backend based on Spring-Boot and display it in frontend based on Angular 5?

I tried this code but I have a 500 error on frontend and a RuntimeException in backend.

Here is the entity Prestataires:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Prestataires implements Serializable 
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String nom;
    private String email;
    private String tele;
    private String fax;
    private String rib;
    private String adresse;
    private String taches;
    //This is the URL of the Photo
    private String photo;

    //-------------------Constructors--------------------
    //--------------------Getters and Setters-------------

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_PRESTATAIRES_TYPES")
    private PrestatairesTypes prestatairesTypes;
}
```

Here is the class to handle the file upload and load:

```
package smart.syndic.metier;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.FileSystemUtils;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import smart.syndic.entities.Prestataires;

@Service
public class StorageService 
{
    private String imageCDN = "http://www.yourHost.com/fichiers/";
    private Path rootLocation;

    public String store(MultipartFile file, String chemin, Object p) {
        String storedLocation = null;
        rootLocation = Paths.get("fichiers/"+chemin+"/");
        String filename = null;

        filename =((Prestataires) p).getId()+"."+file.getOriginalFilename()
        .substring(
                file.getOriginalFilename().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        try {
            if(file.isEmpty()){
                throw new StorageException("Failed to store Empty"
                        + " File "+filename);
            }
            if(filename.contains(".."))
            {
                throw new StorageException("Cannot store file with relative path 
             "
                        + "outside current directory "+filename);
            }

            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), 
       this.rootLocation.resolve(filename), 
                    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            storedLocation = imageCDN + filename;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new StorageException("Failed to store file " + filename, e);
        }
        ((Prestataires) p).setPhoto("fichiers/"+chemin+"/"+filename);
        return storedLocation + chemin+"/";
    }

    // the method that load the file (picture)
    public Resource loadFile(String filename) {
        try {
            Path file = rootLocation.resolve(filename);
            Resource resource = new UrlResource(file.toUri());
            if (resource.exists() || resource.isReadable()) {
                return resource;
            } else {
     // The error that is shown in the backend
                throw new RuntimeException("File doesn't exist or is not 
       readable!");
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("FAIL!");
        }
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(rootLocation.toFile());
    }
}
```

Here is the RestController:

```
package smart.syndic.web;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.
 annotation.MvcUriComponentsBuilder;
import smart.syndic.dao.PrestatairesRepository;
import smart.syndic.dao.PrestatairesTypesRepository;
import smart.syndic.entities.Prestataires;
import smart.syndic.metier.StorageService;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class PrestatairesRestController 
{
    @Autowired
    private PrestatairesRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private PrestatairesTypesRepository repository2;

    @Autowired
    private StorageService storageService;

    private List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Method for getting the Prestataires Object and loading the photo
    @RequestMapping(value="/prestataires/{id}", 
            method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Prestataires getVilles(@PathVariable Long id)
    {

        return repository.findOne(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/prestataires", 
            method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Prestataires addVilles(Prestataires p,
            @RequestParam("multipartFile") MultipartFile file)
    {
        Prestataires pp = null;
        try{
            pp = repository.save(p);
            storageService.store(file, "prestataires",pp);
            files.add(file.getOriginalFilename());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     p.setPrestatairesTypes(
     repository2.findOne(p.getPrestatairesTypes().getId()));
        updateVilles(p.getId(), p);
        return pp;              
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/prestataires/{id}", 
            method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public Prestataires updateVilles(
            @PathVariable Long id,
            @RequestBody Prestataires v)
    {
        v.setId(id);
        return repository.save(v);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/prestataires/{id}", 
            method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public boolean deleteVilles(@PathVariable Long id){
        repository.delete(id);

        return true;
    }
 }
```

Here is the front view:

```
<div class="right_col" role="main">
<div class="">
<div class="page-title">
  <div class="title_left">
    <h3>Prestataires</h3>
  </div>


</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="x_panel">
      <div class="x_title">
        <h2>Voir les Prestataires </h2>
        <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
          <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
  role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a routerLink="/ajouterPrestataires">Ajouter 
  Prestataires</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="x_content">

        <div class="x_content">
          <p class="text-muted font-13 m-b-30">

          </p>
          <div id="containerPrestataires">

          </div>
          <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" 
 for="motCle">Mot Clé <span class="required">*</span>
              </label>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                <input (keyup)="getAllPrestataires(motCle)" 
 [(ngModel)]="motCle" type="text" id="motCle" name="motCle" 
 required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <select [(ngModel)]="size" name="size" class="form-control" 
 (change)="getAllPrestataires(motCle)">
                  <option [value]="5">Afficher 5 Par Page</option>
                  <option [value]="10" selected="selected">Afficher 10 Par 
 Page</option>
                  <option [value]="20">Afficher 20 Par Page</option>
                  <option [value]="30">Afficher 30 Par Page</option>
                  <option [value]="40">Afficher 40 Par Page</option>
                  <option [value]="50">Afficher 50 Par Page</option>
                  <option [value]="100">Afficher 100 Par Page</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>


          </form>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Numero</th>
              <th>Raison Social/Nom</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Telephone</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            <tr *ngFor="let a of allPrestataires; let i = index">
              <td>{{i+1}}</td>
              <td>{{a.nom}}</td>
              <td>{{a.email}}</td>
              <td>{{a.tele}}</td>
              <td>{{a.prestatairesTypes?.designation}}</td>
              <td>

                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data- 
  toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
                        (click)="modifierPrestataires1(a.id)">
                  Modifier
                </button>

                <!-- Button trigger modal Suppression  -->
                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data- 
   target="#myModalSupprimer"
                        class="btn btn-danger" 
   (click)="supprimerPrestataires1(a.id)">
                  Supprimer
                </button>

              </td>
            </tr>


            </tbody>
          </table>

          <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
              <li class="clickable" [ngClass]="{'active':page == iii}"
                  *ngFor="let p of pages; let iii = index">
                <a (click)="goToPage(iii)">{{iii+1}}</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
 aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modifier 
  Prestataires</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <div id="containerModifierPrestataires">

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
  12">Nom/Raison Social<span class="required">*</span></label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input [(ngModel)]="nom" name="nom" class="form- 
 control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
 12">Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input [(ngModel)]="email" name="email" class="form- 
 control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="email" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
 12">Téléphone<span class="required">*</span></label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input [(ngModel)]="tele" name="tele" class="form- 
  control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
12">Fax<span class="required">*</span></label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input [(ngModel)]="fax" name="fax" class="form- 
 control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
   12">RIB<span class="required">*</span></label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input [(ngModel)]="rib" name="rib" class="form- 
   control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
   12">Adresse<span class="required">*</span></label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <textarea [(ngModel)]="adresse" name="adresse" 
  class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" required>
                        </textarea>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
  12">Tâches<span class="required">*</span></label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <textarea [(ngModel)]="taches" name="taches" 
   class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" required>
                        </textarea>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
  12">Photo/Logo<span class="required">*</span></label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input name="multipartFileModifier" class="form- 
    control col-md-7 col-xs-12"
                               type="file" required="required"
                               (change)="handleFileInput($event)">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
 12">Image Preview</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <img class="imagePrestataires" [src]="photo">
                      </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
  12">Nouveau Type<span class="required">*</span></label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <select class="form-control" name="selectTypes" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectTypes">
                            <option selected="selected" *ngFor="let s of 
   tousLesPrestatairesTypes" [value]="s.id" >
                              {{s.designation}}
                            </option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset- 
 3">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" 
  type="reset">Vider</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
 (click)="modifierPrestataires2()">Modifier</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data- 
 dismiss="modal" id="fermer">Fermer</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--  /modal -->

          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModalSupprimer" tabindex="-1" 
   role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
 aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Supprimer 
   Prestataires</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

                    <div id="containerSupprimerPrestataires">

                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset- 
 3">
                        <h2>
                          <label class="label label-danger">
                            Voulez-vous le supprimer maintenant?
                          </label>
                        </h2>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" 
  (click)="supprimerPrestataires2()">OUI</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data- 
  dismiss="modal">NO</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--  /modal -->

          <div class="ln_solid"></div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is the front controller:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {PrestatairesService} from "../../services/prestataires.service";

@Component({
selector: 'app-prestataires',
templateUrl: './prestataires.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./prestataires.component.css']
})
export class PrestatairesComponent implements OnInit {

motCle:any = "";
page:any = 0;
size:any = 5;

pages:any;

allPrestataires:any;

supprimer:any = 0;

nom:any;
email:any;
tele:any;
fax:any;
rib:any;
adresse:any;
taches:any;
photo:any;

onePrestataires:any;

tousLesPrestatairesTypes:any;

selectTypes:any;

fileToUpload:any;

imageURL:any;
constructor(private service:PrestatairesService)
{

}

ngOnInit() {
 this.getAllPrestataires();
}

getAllPrestataires()
{
  this.service.getAllPrestataires(this.motCle, this.page, this.size)
    .subscribe(data=>{
      this.allPrestataires = data.content;
      this.pages = new Array(data.totalPages);

      if(data.totalPages <= this.page)
      {
        this.page = 0;
        this.getAllPrestataires();
      }
    }, err=>{

    }, ()=>{

    });
}

 modifierPrestataires1(id:any)
{
  this.service.modifierPrestataires1(id)
    .subscribe(data=>{
     this.onePrestataires = data;
    this.nom = this.onePrestataires.nom;
    this.email = this.onePrestataires.email;
    this.tele = this.onePrestataires.tele;
    this.fax = this.onePrestataires.fax;
    this.rib = this.onePrestataires.rib;
    this.adresse = this.onePrestataires.adresse;
    this.taches = this.onePrestataires.taches;
    this.photo = "http://localhost:8080/"+this.onePrestataires.photo;
  }, err=>{

  }, ()=>{
      this.getAllTypes();
  });
  }

modifierPrestataires2()
{
 // Code here to update Prestataires
}

 supprimerPrestataires1(id:any){
this.supprimer = id;
 }

 supprimerPrestataires2()
 {
  this.service.supprimerPrestataires(this.supprimer)
  .subscribe(data=>{

    this.getAllPrestataires();
  }, err=>{

  }, ()=>{

  });
 }


 goToPage(id:any)
 {
this.page = id;
this.getAllPrestataires();
}

getAllTypes()
{
  this.service.getAllTypes()
  .subscribe(data=>{
    this.tousLesPrestatairesTypes = data;
  }, err=>{

  }, ()=>{

  });
 }

handleFileInput(file:any)
{
this.fileToUpload = <File>file.target.files[0];
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (event:any)=>{
  this.photo = event.target.result;
}

reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileToUpload);
 }
}
```

Here is the Service class:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
 import {HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpRequest} from 
 "@angular/common/http";

 @Injectable()
 export class PrestatairesService
 {
   host:string = "http://localhost:8080/";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient)
 {

 }

 getAllPrestataires(motCle:any, page:any, size:any)
 {
   return this.http.get(this.host + "prestataires? 
   motCle="+motCle+"&page="+page+"&size="+size);
 }

supprimerPrestataires(id:any)
{
 return this.http.delete(this.host + "prestataires/" + id);
}

getAllTypes()
{
 return this.http.get(this.host + "prestatairesTypes");
}

ajouterType(model:any)
{
  return this.http.post(this.host + "prestatairesTypes", model);
}

getOneType(id:any)
{
  return this.http.get(this.host + "prestatairesTypes/" + id);
}

 ajouterPrestataires(model:any)
 {
   return this.http.post(this.host + "prestataires", model);
 }

 uploadFile(model:any)
{


let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('multipartFile', model.file);
formData.append('nom', model.nom);
formData.append('email', model.email);
formData.append('rib', model.rib);
formData.append('taches', model.taches);
formData.append('fax', model.fax);
formData.append('adresse', model.adresse);
formData.append('tele', model.tele);
formData.append('prestatairesTypes', model.prestatairesTypes);

let params = new HttpParams();

const options = {
  params: params,
  reportProgress: true,
};

const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.host+"prestataires", formData, 
 options);
  return this.http.request(req);
 }

 modifierPrestataires1(id:any){
   return this.http.get(this.host + "prestataires/" + id);
 }
}
```

#### Here is the Exception in frontend:

```
GET 404:
GET http://localhost:8080/fichiers/prestataires/48.jpg 404
```

Comment: _"a RuntimeException in backend"_, please post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: Please **edit** your question, don't use comments to add information and make sure to post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: i updated the post.